# how to remove or hide a div from a iframe added

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

I am not able to remove on div from iframe from my website http://dubaimarketingexperts.com/index.html
[div to be removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3liF.png)

```
<iframe title="Dubai Free SEO Quote" 
    src="" allowtransparency="true" 
    allow="geolocation; microphone; camera" 
    allowfullscreen="true" 
    name="41015223436139" 
    id="41015223436139" 
    scrolling="no"
    style="width: 10px; min-width: 100%; display: block; overflow: hidden; border: medium none; height: 225px;" >
</iframe>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#41015223436139").contents().find(".black-friday-2019").remove();
    });
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are both the website and iframe under the same domain? If so, try the following script in your iframe's page

```
if (window.self !== window.top) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".black-friday-2019").forEach(el => el.remove());
} else {
  document.querySelectorAll(".black-friday-2019").forEach(el => el.add());
}
```